# How to distribute compiled framework using Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm building a framework using cocoapods. Now, I have it in a private repository with a private spec repo. I want to distribute this framework not as open source, but closed source. Basically, I want to distribute only the .framework file, already compiled. This way, I will avoid to expose my source code to externals.
I don't know how to tell cocoapods to distribute the compiled file.

Answer (score 3):

After compiling your framework, you'll want to create a separate, public repository to use for distribution. That is where you will place your compiled framework, podspec, license, readme files, etc.

The podspec is a bit different for distributing frameworks rather than source code. See example:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|  
    s.name              = 'YourFrameworkName'
    s.version           = '1.7.0'
    s.summary           = 'The YourFrameworkName iOS SDK enables you to embed state-of-the-art real-time goodness into your iOS app.'
    s.homepage          = 'http://example.com'

    s.author            = { 'Name' => 'info@example.com' }
    s.license           = { :type => 'Custom', :file => 'LICENSE' }

    s.platform          = :ios
    s.source            = { :http => 'https://github.com/example/YourFrameworkName/releases/download/1.7.0/YourFrameworkName.zip' }

    s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
    s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'YourFrameworkName.framework'

    s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON', '3.1.4'
end
```

Once all that is set up, you can publish the pod spec the normal way.

Keep in mind, and this is an important consideration, that your compiled framework written in Swift will only be usable in projects that use the ***exact same*** Swift version. You will quickly run into this limitation as people start using your framework in different projects with various Swift versions.

Comment: Here is an example of a Cocoapod repository that uses this technique. Note that I am no longer affiliated with this project and am not endorsing or promoting this framework, only using it as an example of what the OP is trying to do. https://github.com/tallygo/TallyGoKit

Comment: Ok, got it. Now I'm having two problems : 1) My repository is private as the pod I'm developing is internal to the company. I need the framework to avoid that, in case of collaboration with external, our source code could be seen by not authorized people. The podspec verifications fails because the github url points to private repo. 2) You say "After compiling your framework", what do you mean? Isn't this something that cocoapods has to do automatically?

Comment: No. You would manually compile your framework and then commit that to the public repository. The pod spec should only reference the public repository.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you create a sample project and install the pods(the library which you want to release as *SDK.framework*) for the project.
2. Then see the below-attached image to get the *.framework* extension file to distribute to the public.

   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by pointing `s.source` of the `podspec` file to a zip file of your framework and its source. No need to expose your source in a public repository.

ex.

```
spec.source = { :http => 'https://bitbucket.org/publicRepo/yourframework.zip' }
```